# VersionControlServer.QueryHistory returning System.Collections.IEnumerable / System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

Looking at the `QueryHistory` method overloads of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.queryhistory.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

It seems that some overloads return `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Changeset>`
and others return `System.Collections.IEnumerable` .

Is there an easy way to convert a `System.Collections.IEnumerable` (containing `Changeset` items) to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Changeset>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure the collection only contains `ChangeSet` items you can use the Linq extension method `Cast()`:

```
IEnumerable myCollection = ...
IEnumerable<ChangeSet> myGenericCollection = myCollection.Cast<ChangeSet>();
```

If you're not entirely sure the collection only contains `ChangeSet` you can filter it with another Linq extension method `OfType()`:

```
IEnumerable myCollection = ...
IEnumerable<ChangeSet> myGenericCollection = myCollection.OfType<ChangeSet>();
```